# TypeScript Promises not executing sequentially

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I am learning Promise using TypeScript currently and I hope someone can help me understand why the following promises are not executing sequentially as I want them to do, I have tried googled this stuff for 2 days without luck, so please feel free to share some ideas, thank you very much.

```ts
step1()
.then(() => {
      return step2();
})
.then(() => {
      return step3();
});

function step1() : Promise<void>{
        return new Promise<void>(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {console.log("1");}, 1000);
        });
}

function step2() : Promise<void>{
        return new Promise<void>(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {console.log("2");}, 1000);
        });
}

function step3() : Promise<void>{
        return new Promise<void>(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {console.log("3");}, 1000);
        });
}
```

It stops at step 1 and none of the other functions are ever called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your promise is void, you still have to call the resolve function to indicate that you're finished.

Instead of

```
return new Promise<void>(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {console.log("1");}, 1000);
});
```

Try

```
return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {console.log("1"); resolve()}, 1000);
});
```

in each function

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much dude, you just saved my life! have a nice day sir.